# IF Statements in formula fields with Date function

Tags: formula

I have what I was hoping was a simple formula field with an IF statement to populate two different dates based on the presence of a value. I have two fields StartDate and Trial_End_Date__c. I need to populate a date in a field called Initial_Credit_Month__c. This field would contain the value of Trial_End_Date__c plus 1 month if it is not blank. If it is blank, then my Initial_Credit_Month__c field would contain the value of StartDate plus 1 month.  Here is what I tried, but getting syntax errors:

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(Account.Trial_End_Date__c)
), 
ADDMONTHS (StartDate,0)), 
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Trial_End_Date__c)
), 
ADDMONTHS (Account.Trial_End_Date__c,0), 
NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in `IF()` statement itself. The syntax for IF() is as below.

```
IF( expression to be evaluated, result when true, result when false).
```

In your scenario the expression is to check if Trial_End_Date__c is blank or not so your expression would be `ISBLANK(Account.Trial_End_Date__c)`.

If that is blank you have to add 1 month to Start Date so the true condition would be `ADDMONTHS (StartDate,1)`.

If Trial_End_Date__c is not null then we have to ass 1 month to the Trial_End_Date__c so the false condition should return `ADDMONTHS (Account.Trial_End_Date__c,1)`. So the total formula will look as below.

```
IF(ISBLANK(Account.Trial_End_Date__c), ADDMONTHS (StartDate,1),ADDMONTHS (Account.Trial_End_Date__c,1))
```

We may also check the BLANK condition for StartDate as well so you may need to add another if condition for startdate and formula may look as below.

```
IF(ISBLANK(Account.Trial_End_Date__c), IF(ISBLANK(StartDate),Null,ADDMONTHS (StartDate,1)),ADDMONTHS (Account.Trial_End_Date__c,1))
```

which means if Trial_End_Date__c and StartDate both are blank then it should return Blank.